How to skip checking third-party dependencies when using clang-tidy?
I'm using clang-tidy in my C++ project, and I'm encountering errors related to third-party dependencies, specifically Abseil (absl). I want to skip checking these dependencies.
jiawei@DESKTOP-AEQS7B5:~/Development/OSM2GMNS/OSM2GMNS$ pre-commit run
trim trailing whitespace.................................................Passed
check for added large files..............................................Passed
check yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
clang-format.............................................................Passed
clang-tidy...............................................................Failed
- hook id: clang-tidy
- exit code: 1

b'as error\n'
/home/jiawei/Development/OSM2GMNS/OSM2GMNS/cmake-build-debug/_deps/absl-src/absl/container/internal/raw_hash_set.h:520:44: error: The value '0' provided to the cast expression is not in the valid range of values for 'ctrl_t' [clang-analyzer-optin.core.EnumCastOutOfRange,-warnings-as-errors]
  520 | inline bool IsFull(ctrl_t c) { return c >= static_cast<ctrl_t>(0); }

Here's my current setup:
CMakeLists.txt
cmakeCopyFetchContent_Declare(
    absl
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
    GIT_TAG 20230125.3
    SYSTEM
)

.pre-commit-config.yaml:
fail_fast: false
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.5.0
    hooks:
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: check-added-large-files
      - id: check-yaml
        exclude: ".clang-*"
  - repo: https://github.com/jiawlu/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: 49cddc161d4fe41ee9f16922f2c0e634b0a115ff
    hooks:
      - id: clang-format
        args: [--style=file, -i]
      - id: clang-tidy
        args: [-p=./cmake-build-debug, --fix-errors]

.clang-tidy
Checks: '*,-=,-fuchsia-*,-zircon-*,-modernize-use-trailing-return-type,-hicpp-use-emplace,-modernize-use-emplace,-llvm-*,-llvmlibc-*,-readability-function-cognitive-complexity,-altera-*,-openmp-exception-escape,-cppcoreguidelines-owning-memory,-bugprone-easily-swappable-parameters,-bugprone-branch-clone'
WarningsAsErrors: '*'
HeaderFilterRegex: 'src/.*'
FormatStyle: 'file'

versions
clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 18.1.3 (1ubuntu1)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang-tidy --version
Ubuntu LLVM version 18.1.3
  Optimized build
pre-commit --version
pre-commit 3.6.2

Despite using the SYSTEM flag in FetchContent_Declare and setting HeaderFilterRegex to 'src/.*', clang-tidy is still checking the Abseil headers and reporting errors.
How can I configure clang-tidy to skip checking third-party dependencies like Abseil while still analyzing my own code?

pre-commit works by passing checked-in files to hooks
as you've configured clang-tidy:
      - id: clang-tidy
        args: [-p=./cmake-build-debug, --fix-errors]

you are using the default filtering options:
    types_or: [c, c++, c#, objective-c]

this means that clang-tidy will be invoked (as per the docs)
clang-tidy -p=./cmake-build-debug --fix-errors filename filename filename

where each filename is one which matches types_or: [...] from above
in order to not pass your vendored files you can use one of the file filtering options (probably exclude in your case) such as:
      - id: clang-tidy
        args: [-p=./cmake-build-debug, --fix-errors]
        exclude: ^cmake-build-debug/_deps/

though it's strange that you've checked in your _deps in the first place -- usually that's .gitignored.  you could also use a top-level exclude:
exclude: ^cmake-build-debug/_deps/


disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

the error still exists, no matter I add exclude: ^cmake-build-debug/_deps/ under - id: clang-tidy or at the top level. the code I shared in my original post actually works fine on my mac machine with clang/clang-tidy 17.0.6 and pre-commit 3.7.0 installed

what's the file path relative to your repository root?

.pre-commit-config.yaml and .clang-tidy are in my repo root

It works fine after I downgrade clang/clang-tidy to version 17
